# Flutter local notification onSelectNotification can not open a new page when a local notification is clicked

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want my flutter app to open a page when a local notification is clicked. I've defined the following codes in the event listener:

```
Navigator.push(
   Ccontext,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PendingOrders()),
 );
debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
```

The event listener is executed successfully and printed the debugPrint's parameter when a local notification is called but it can not open the PendingOrders route.

Here is the full code in the main.dart

```
  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  var android = AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var ios =  IOSInitializationSettings();
  var platform = InitializationSettings(android, ios);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(platform,onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

  _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('order-created');
  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onMessage: $message");
      showNotification(message);
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onLaunch: $message");
      print("Hafijur");
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print("onResume: ${message['notification']['data']['click_action']}");
    },
  );
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
}

showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
  var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'sdffds dsffds',
    "CHANNLE NAME",
    "channelDescription",
  );
  var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, "New order arrived", "Hey, hurry up! you have a order to deliver", platform,payload: "order created");
}
 Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
  this.build(context);
   Navigator.push(
     context,
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PendingOrders()),
   );
   if (payload != null) {
    debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: Constants.lightTheme,
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    routes: {
      "/": (context) => MainScreen(),
      "/login": (context) => LoginPage(),
      "/dashboard": (context) => Dashboard(),
      "/all_orders": (context) => AllOrders(),
      "/pending_orders": (context) => PendingOrders(),
      "/delivered_orders": (context) => DeliveredOrders(),
      "/order": (context) => Order(),
    },
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Facing same issue

Comment: onSelectNotification not working if app closed any hope ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
var initializationSettingsAndroid =
          const AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/icon_menu_car_no');
      var initializationSettingsIOs = const IOSInitializationSettings();
      var initSettings = InitializationSettings(
          android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
          iOS: initializationSettingsIOs);
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin?.initialize(initSettings,
          onSelectNotification: (payload) {
           switch(payload){
               case "A":
                 //route  to some where 
                break;

           }
      });

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
       showNotification(message);
});
```

```
void showNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
      var messageData = FirebaseMessageObject.fromJson(message.data);
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin?.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel!.id,
              channel!.name,
              channelDescription: channel!.description,
              icon: 'icon_menu_car_no',
            ),
          ),
          payload: messageData.functionID);
    }
  }
```

```
class FirebaseMessageObject{
  late String functionID;

  static FirebaseMessageObject fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> data){
    FirebaseMessageObject object =  FirebaseMessageObject();
    object.functionID = data['functionID'];
    return object;
  }

}
```

※FCM Request

```
{
    "to": "your fcm token ",
    "notification": {
         "body": "I am body ",
         "title": "I am title ",
         "sound": "default"
    },
    "data":{
            "functionID":"A"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Answer (score 19):

To receive payload when app was closed after open with tapping on notification then you have to use **getNotificationAppLaunchDetails** method

```
final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
String? payload = notificationAppLaunchDetails!.payload;
```

put this code in main after notification initialization lines

use **onSelectNotification** will be triggered only if the app is already open when tapping notification.

but if the app is already closed and you want to run it after tapping notification with handling the payload value then you have to use **getNotificationAppLaunchDetails**

code will be something like following:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var initializationSettingsIOs = IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initSetttings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOs);
  var cnf = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
      onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();

  print('payload=');
  String? payload= notificationAppLaunchDetails!.payload;
  print(payload);

    runApp(
         MaterialApp(        
          home: payload== 'page1' ? Page1() : MainPage()
         )
       ); 
}
```

Comment: very good tip indeed, it helped me and solved my issue

Comment: but if we want to open the app on notification click when app is terminated then what to do?

Comment: why Payload is empty when I click on notification I can't get notification data !

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue but this fixed my problem

```
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        displayNotification(message);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
        return;
      },
    );
```

```
void _navigateToItemDetail(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    Navigator.popUntil(context, (Route<dynamic> route) => route is PageRoute);
    await Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false, pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => NewPage();

  }
```